# TimeZoneInfo Ambiguous one hour before needed

Tags: c#, dst

Working with TimeZoneInfo I have run into a problem. It might just be a question of understanding the ideas Microsoft has put into TimeZoneInfo.

The problem is that if I run these lines of code:

```
var tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
bool result = tzi.IsAmbiguousTime(new DateTime(2013, 11, 3, 1, 15, 0));
```

result is true.

At November 3rd we're supposed to change back to normal time from daylight savings, so at 2:59:5999999 the time will change to 2:00:00

So why is the time stamp 01:15:00 an ambiguous time?

Comment: @Jon is right; daylight-saving time rules move from 01:59:59 EDT to 01:00:00 EST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your statement is not correct: the time will change at 02:00 local time (which means: EDT) and shift back to 01:00 EST. This means that there will be *two* instances of 01:15:00, hence the result should be expected.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone):

> During the first Sunday in November, at 2:00 a.m. EDT, clocks are
>   moved back to 1:00 a.m. EST, thus "duplicating" one hour.

It's interesting to note that you can disambiguate between the two by explicitly stating if the time is EDT or EST.

Comment: Argh ! You are right. Got confused because most european countries change to normal time at at 3:00. Thanks